# Google ctemplate repeat a section only sometimes

Tags: parsing, xml-parsing, google-ctemplate

We have a section that looks like that ...

```
{{#PRIZES}}
<div style="text-align: left;TTS={{date}}">{{date}}</div>
<div style="text-align: left;TTS={{sign}}">{{sign}}</div>
<div style="text-align: center;TTS={{number}}">{{number}}</div>
<div style="text-align: right;TTS={{serie}}">{{serie}}</div>
<br>
    {{#ADD}}
    <div style="text-align: left;TTS={{sign}}">{{sign1}}</div>
    <div style="text-align: left;TTS={{number}}">{{number}}</div>
    <div style="text-align: right;TTS={{serie}}">{{serie}}</div>
    <br>
    {{/ADD}}
{{/PRIZES}}
```

We want that section add looks sometimes 0, or sometimes N for each iteration of Prizes section.

The problem is that I only can repeat ADD section same times for each prizes section.